# HTTP POST request in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, http, dart, rest

Hi I hope everyone's doing fine, I'm new to flutter building my first application and I have to add a `contact` in flutter using RestAPI. The problem is I'm not getting any right way to do it.

I'm using `HTTP Client` and the response status code is supposed to be `201`, I am successfully getting this response when I call my `addContact()` function in the `Main class` but not when I call it in the `add_contacts class`.

I have successfully created the model also using `quicktype.io` tool and in the UI part I have a `form` and for now I've created it in such a way that when I click on save, it shows a `container` with `text` that my contact is saved but since I'm not getting the response only in that class I can't verify also whether the contact is saved or not.

Also I don't know how to actually `post` all the contact details from the form, I've added all the necessary `controllers` and everything but I want to post all the contact details when I click on save.

According to my `API Documentation` I can post any contact field alias as a `parameter`. For example, firstname, lastname, email, etc.

**I'm hoping someone could guide me through this, all the codes I have attached below.
Thank You.**

**API_Manager class:**

```
Future<AddContactModel> addContact(
    String firstName,
    String lastName,
    String email,
  ) async {
    var client = http.Client();
    String addContactUrl =
        "https://example.com/ma/api/contacts/new";
    String basicAuth = 'Basic exampleauthkey';
    var response = await client.post(addContactUrl, headers: <String, String>{
      'authorization': basicAuth,
      "Accept": "application/json",
    }, body: {
      "firstname": firstName,
      "lastname": lastName,
      "email": email
    });
    print(response.statusCode);
    //developer.log(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      final String responseString = response.body;
      return addContactModelFromJson(responseString);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

**add_contact class:**

```
class _AddContactsState extends State<AddContacts> {
  AddContactModel _contact;
  TextEditingController _ipCountryCode,
      _eventRevenue,
      _sendsSinceLastEngagement,
      _marketingEmailsOpened,
      _socialAwarenessClicks,
      _firstName,
      _lastName,
      _email,
      _reasonForEmailUnsubscribe;

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String contactOwner,
      stage,
      leadStatus,
      tags,
      emailAddressQuarantined,
      selectCompany;
  DateTime timeFirstSeen,
      lastMarketingEmailClickDate,
      createDate,
      becameAnEvangelistDate;
  List contactOwnerItem = [
    "example owner 1",
    "example owner 2",
    "example owner 3",
    "example owner 4"
  ];
  List stageItem = [
    "Stage 1",
    "Stage 2",
    "Stage 3",
    "Stage 4",
  ];
  List leadStatusItem = [
    "Status 1",
    "Status 2",
    "Status 3",
    "Status 4",
  ];
  List tagsItem = [
    "tag1",
    "tag2",
    "tag3",
    "tag4",
  ];
  List emailAddressQuarantinedItem = ["On", "Off"];
  List selectCompanyItem = ["Company 1", "Other"];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _ipCountryCode = TextEditingController();
    _eventRevenue = TextEditingController();
    _sendsSinceLastEngagement = TextEditingController();
    _marketingEmailsOpened = TextEditingController();
    _socialAwarenessClicks = TextEditingController();
    _firstName = TextEditingController();
    _lastName = TextEditingController();
    _reasonForEmailUnsubscribe = TextEditingController();
    _email = TextEditingController();
  }

  Future saveContact() async{
    final String firstName = _firstName.text;
    final String lastName = _lastName.text;
    final String email = _email.text;

    final AddContactModel contact = await  API_Manager().addContact(firstName, lastName, email);

    setState(() {
      _contact = contact;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Add Contact'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                textColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {
                  // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false otherwise.
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    saveContact();
                  }
                },
                child: Text(
                  'SAVE',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
                shape:
                    CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
              )
            ],
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  _contact == null ? Container() :
                  Text("The user ${_contact.contact.fields.all.firstname} is created successfully and was last active at time ${_contact.contact.lastActive.toIso8601String()}"),
                  TextFormField(
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _ipCountryCode,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'IP Country Code',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DateTimeFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Time First Seen',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
                            setState(() {
                              timeFirstSeen = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _eventRevenue,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Event Revenue',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _sendsSinceLastEngagement,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Sends since last engagement',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _marketingEmailsOpened,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Marketing Emails Opened',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DateTimeFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Last marketing email click date',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
                            setState(() {
                              lastMarketingEmailClickDate = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          isExpanded: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Email Address Quarantined',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          value: emailAddressQuarantined,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              emailAddressQuarantined = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: emailAddressQuarantinedItem.map((valueItem) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: valueItem,
                              child: Text(valueItem),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _socialAwarenessClicks,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Social Awareness Clicks',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Lead Status',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          value: leadStatus,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              leadStatus = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: leadStatusItem.map((valueItem) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: valueItem,
                              child: Text(valueItem),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DateTimeFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Create date',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
                            setState(() {
                              createDate = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DateTimeFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Became an evangelist date',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
                            setState(() {
                              becameAnEvangelistDate = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _firstName,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'First Name',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _lastName,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Last Name',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    //validator: validateEmail,
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _email,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Email',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _reasonForEmailUnsubscribe,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Reason for email unsubscribe',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          isExpanded: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Tags',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          value: tags,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              tags = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: tagsItem.map((valueItem) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: valueItem,
                              child: Text(valueItem),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          isExpanded: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Select a company',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          value: selectCompany,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectCompany = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: selectCompanyItem.map((valueItem) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: valueItem,
                              child: Text(valueItem),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          isExpanded: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Contact Owner',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          value: contactOwner,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              contactOwner = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: contactOwnerItem.map((valueItem) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: valueItem,
                              child: Text(valueItem),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Stage',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          value: stage,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              stage = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: stageItem.map((valueItem) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: valueItem,
                              child: Text(valueItem),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

*I've given all static data to the `DropdownButtonFormField` for now, but I need to populate it with the api response, please help me achieve that too.*

**Here's how my UI for the form looks:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

there are many questions here you have given but for`async` code try adding the `await`

```dart
onPressed: () async {
    // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false otherwise.
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) async {
       await saveContact();
       }
   },
```

to send all the form data to your server, just add more fields as you have done here, from the textcontrollers you have defined

```dart
// add all fields you want to post to server here
final AddContactModel contact = await  API_Manager().addContact(firstName, lastName, email, ..);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but can you tell me how to pass the entire JSON as parameter instead of `firstName, lastName, email`. Because I have a lot of fields and I can't pass each and everyone as parameters to the function.